# The resultset returns empty when connecting with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

I'm trying to execute a query in database in MySQL using `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet`.

The problem is that I am getting an empty result set in MySQL, otherwise I get a correct result on Derby.

```
Connection con= null;
ResultSet reslt =null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try 
{
    //Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SAIID","SAIID","SAIID"); 
    //con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/pavillons","saiid","saiid"); 
    String Query =" SELECT * FROM ETUDIANT_PAV WHERE PAVILLONS = ? AND CHAMBRE = ? "

    ps = con.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    ps.setString(1, "A");
    ps.setString(2, "1");
    reslt = ps.executeQuery();
    //String thequeryresult= reslt.getString("NOM_PRENOM");
    //System.out.println ("this is the query result"+thequeryresult);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Query Executed");
    //con.close();


}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());

}
```

Comment: Is Chambre a varchar or a number type in the DB table?

Comment: chambre is a varchar.

Comment: How do you know that Result is empty?

Comment: //String thequeryresult= reslt.getString("NOM_PRENOM");
    //System.out.println ("this is the query result"+thequeryresult); 
it says that NOM_PRENOM do not exist.

Comment: Why is it tag `phpmyadmin` ? It is an administration tool from MySql. This has nothing to do with JDBC <-> MySQL. You need to read the `ResultSet`, by starting to move the cursor on the first line with `reslt.next()`

Comment: the problem is that i am using this function in a form application and i need to deploy it in a desktop, i used to do my test in derby jdbc and now i have to use mysql (phpmyadmin) in the desktop. so when use the mysql connector iget an empty resultset when it works correctly in derby.

Comment: i am using the resultset.next() correctly alsow.

Comment: Where ?? Provide a [mcve] then ! The reason it return an empty resultset might be because the DB SAIID don't have any row in ETUDIANT_PAV ? Have you run that in a command shell or phpmyadmin (the web page) FYI: PhpmyAdmin is not a DB, MySQL is. PHPMyAdmin is just a tool that give you a nice GUI to manage your DB

Comment: yes i did insert some rows for the tset and when i run the query in webpage it returns a correct result.

Comment: here a part from the code that uses the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing this lines :

```
reslt = ps.executeQuery();
//String thequeryresult= reslt.getString("NOM_PRENOM");
```

If you used that commented line to checked the result, this can't worked. You need to move the cursor of that result set to the first line (start to -1).

For that, use [`ResultSet.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) that will return `true` until there is no more row to read.

```
reslt = ps.executeQuery(); 
while(reslt.next()){ //read all lines
    System.out.println(reslt.getString("NOM_PRENOM"));
}
```

Comment: i tried this and i get this message : column NOM_PRENOM not found

Comment: @djalellabed Well, check the content of your table `ETUDIANT_PAV` for that. But that's proving there is a result since it entered the loop... Just used the correct column name

Comment: thanks it working now it was the column name thannnnnnks

Comment: Remember to accept the answer that help you the most to "close" a question.

Comment: how to do that please.

Answer (score -1):

```
String selctedItemPAV = indextostring(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()); 
       String selctedItemCH = jList1.getSelectedValue();
       String Query =" SELECT * FROM etudiant_pav WHERE PAVILLONS = ? AND CHAMBRE = ? " ;
       rst = theSelectQuery(Query,selctedItemPAV ,selctedItemCH); //this is the posted function 
         DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
         jList3.setModel(listModel);
         System.out.println (selctedItemCH + "  doppppppppp  " +selctedItemPAV + jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex());

          System.out.println ("doppppppppp222222222");
     if (rst.isBeforeFirst())
     {
          System.out.println ("ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt");    //the excution stops here in application.....
         jList3.setEnabled(true);
         listModel.clear();
         jLabel1.setVisible(false);
        while (rst.next()) 
        {
             String aff="hhh";
             aff= rst.getString("NOM_PRENOM");
             System.out.println ("dooooooooo"+aff);
            listModel.addElement(aff);
         }
        }
     else 
     {
         jLabel1.setVisible(false);
          jList3.setEnabled(false);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "la chambre est vide ");
     }

     rst.close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex){
  }
```

Comment: use the `edit` to post a [mcve] in your question. Not that complete version of code in an answer.

Comment: `isBeforeFirst()` is (a) optional and (b) generally bound to be true on a brand new `ResultSet`, whether empty or not.